# error: in triplet x64-windows: Unable to find a valid Visual Studio instance Could not locate a complete Visual Studio instance

Tags: c, include

I am trying to start coding so I started watching the Cs50 course.
Now i am trying to use VsCode as my program editor because I know it's pretty good and it is the same editor they use in the Cs50 lecture, but when i try to include libraries like stdio or cs50 it spits out "#include-Fehler erkannt. Aktualisieren Sie Ihren includePath. Wellenlinien sind für diese Übersetzungseinheit". I've tried a couple of things and now installed Vcpkg. While trying to install cs50 by typing ".\vcpkg install cs50" into my PowerShell Window i got the error message "error: while looking for cs50:x86-windows:
error: while loading cs50:
The port directory (C:\Users\felix\DEV\vcpkg\ports\cs50) does not exist" so i tried to install something else first to make sure it works.
I copied what the guy in my Youtube Video typed in to install sqlite3 but now i get the error message "error: in triplet x64-windows: Unable to find a valid Visual Studio instance
Could not locate a complete Visual Studio instance
The following paths were examined for Visual Studio instances:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary/Build\vcvarsall.bat".
I added english as a supported language in Visual Stuio Installer but it didn't help and all the other solution people talked about were not comprehendable for me.

I hope someone can help me and if you can please try to explain it in simple terms as i am failry new to this whole thing.
Sorry for my bad english and thank you all in advance

Comment: The error is looking for a Visual Studio 2022 Community installation, not VSCode. Do you have both installed?

Comment: When i open my Visual Studio Installer the only installed version is Vs Community 2022

Comment: Make sure you have Desktop development with C++ checked in the installer.

Comment: That fixes the problem I had but i still can't include cs50

Answer (score 3):

select and install "Visual C++ tools for CMake" in the Visual Studio Installer

https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/22074